# Find expected no of turns given each turn you eat single type of food and eating type 0 ends the game

Tags: algorithm, probability

You are given N types of food. Each type i has A[i] number of packets of that type. In each turn you eat all packets of one particular type randomly amongst left food types. Additionally if you eat Type 0 food, this game ends. We need to find expected number of turns before game ends.

I have a O(2^N) clever bitmask solution but apparently there exists a linear solution. I think it uses Linearity of expectation but I am not able to formulate it. I face problem because probability denominator changes with change in permutation of same sequence. I am stuck in this problem for a week and still not able to solve it, kindly help. Tia :)

Comment: Very unclear. Once I ate `i`th food, what am I supposed to do next? Like, eat an arbitrary food -- or eat an `i+1`th food -- or leave -- or what?

Comment: @user58697 you pick any arbitrary food type which has or been eaten yet randomly. You leave once you eat food type 0.

Comment: I think you're thinking too "algorithmically" here -- you're thinking about how to simulate a particular random trial of this system.  Hint: There are N disjoint categories of outcomes: 1. You eat 0 non-0 foods, followed by food 0; 2. You eat 1 non-0 food, followed by food 0; ...; N. You eat N-1 non-0 foods, followed by food 0.  Since these outcome categories are all disjoint, you can use linearity of expectations here.

Comment: @j_random_hacker , I have already thought this way, but in this approach i wasn't able to compute the individual answer. Let me know if you got the answer using this approach?

Comment: After eating food of non-zero type `i`, is it correct to say that we set `A[i] <- 0` and recurse? Also, is the probability of picking food of type `i` `A[i]/sum(A)`? Or is it just `1/(N-turns)`? I just want to make sure I understand the question enough to simulate the game.